# PYSNMP : TypeError: setComponentByType() got multiple values for keyword argument 'verifyConstraints'

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

Facing New issue with PYSNMP 4.3.3. Python 2.7.13.With SNMP GET and Getnext:
Same is working fine with Pysnmp 4.3.2.
The issue actually I am observing when it's involved with virtual env.
in the virtual env even if I downgrade Pysnmp from 4.3.3 to 4.3.2 the issue is getting reproduced.

Can some one please tell me what I am missing ?

**TypeError: setComponentByType() got multiple values for keyword argument 'verifyConstraints'**

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import *
>>> errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
...     getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
...            CommunityData('public'),
...            UdpTransportTarget(('127.0.0.1', 161)),
...            ContextData(),
...            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB','sysDescr', 0)))
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/sourav/MyWorkSpace/tempproject_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/sync/cmdgen.py", line 111, in getCmd
    lookupMib=options.get('lookupMib', True)))
  File "/home/sourav/MyWorkSpace/tempproject_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/cmdgen.py", line 131, in getCmd
    options.get('cbFun'), options.get('cbCtx'))
  File "/home/sourav/MyWorkSpace/tempproject_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdgen.py", line 214, in sendVarBinds
    v2c.apiPDU.setVarBinds(reqPDU, varBinds)
  File "/home/sourav/MyWorkSpace/tempproject_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/api/v1.py", line 136, in setVarBinds
    varBindList.getComponentByPosition(idx), varBind
  File "/home/sourav/MyWorkSpace/tempproject_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/api/v1.py", line 43, in setOIDVal
    verifyConstraints=False)
TypeError: setComponentByType() got multiple values for keyword argument 'verifyConstraints'
>>>
```

**With old style also the same:**

```
>>> from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
>>> cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
>>> errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('127.0.0.1', 161), timeout=60, retries=3),cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB','sysDescr',0))
```

In the link bellow please refer the last two comment. 
https://github.com/home-assistant/home-assistant/issues/5790

Packages used:

```
appdirs==1.4.2
packaging==16.8
ply==3.10
pyasn1==0.2.3
pycryptodome==3.4.5
pyparsing==2.1.10
pysmi==0.0.7
pysnmp==4.3.3
six==1.10.0
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Update:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
after downgrading **Pyasn1 to 0.1.9 from pyasn1==0.2.3** it seems the code is working as usual. But the problem is while fresh install of Pysnmp 4.3.3 its taking Pyasn1==0.2.3 and its failing.

Answer (score 5):

That's an unfortunate regression in pyasn1/pysnmp interaction.

You could fix that by either downgrading pyasn1 to 0.2.2 or taking pysnmp from [git master](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp) or wait a little bit till fixed pysnmp comes out.

Comment: @illya Etingof Thanks a lot for the help we'll wait for the fix and use 0.2.2 meantime.

Comment: pysnmp 4.3.4 is out!